# Submitting job applications rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

Sorry for the fairly general question but I am looking to find out what would be the best way to implement a job application system in rails.

What I currently have is a user model and job model. What I would like to happen is that when a user submits an application for the job, most likely through a seperate application model, the user who posted the job will receive the application in their "applications area" and will also receive an email to the job owner's email address.

Is the best way to set this up to associate applications with users through jobs? Also would I need a seperate database table to handle the application or would it be possible to just set this up using Actionmailer?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a pretty straightforward has_many through association

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :applications
  has_many :jobs, :through => :applications
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :applications
  has_many :users, :through => :applications
end
```

Then in their application area you can just query `user.jobs` or `user.applications` depending on which you want to display.